# Change colors of two y-axes with Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My code is:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xls','data')

sns.regplot(x='X var', y='Y var1',fit_reg=False, data=df)
ax2 = plt.twinx()
sns.regplot(x='X var', y='Y var2', ax=ax2, fit_reg=False,
            color='r',data=df)
```

I would like "Y var1" title to be blue and the "Y var2" title to be red if possible. Either this or a legend that indicates which scatter plot corresponds to which axes.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I found was:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xls','data')

ax1 = sns.regplot(x='X var', y='Y var1',fit_reg=False, data=df)

ax1.set_ylabel('Y var1', color='b')

ax2 = plt.twinx()

ax2.set_ylabel('Y var2', color='r')

ax3 = sns.regplot(x='X var', y='Y var2', ax=ax2, fit_reg=False,
            color='r',data=df)
```